# Как удалить строки, если в них много NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть фрейм вида:

```
 a   b   c    d
NaN  4  NaN  NaN
24   25  34  NaN
NaN  12 NaN  NaN
34  NaN  2    34
NaN NaN  19   11
42  NaN  29  NaN 
54  NaN  11   12
```

Нужно удалить из него строки, в которых число NaN превышает число столбцов с численными значениями или равно ему.

Желаемый результат:

```
 a   b   c    d
24   25  34  NaN
34  NaN  2    34
54  NaN  11   12
```

Мой код:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN, 4, np.NaN, np.NaN], [24, 25, 34, np.NaN], [np.NaN, 12, np.NaN, np.NaN],
                   [34, np.NaN, 2, 34], [np.NaN, np.NaN, 19, 11], [42, np.NaN, 29, np.NaN], [54, np.NaN, 11, 12]])
df.rename({0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'c', 3: 'd'}, axis=1, inplace=True)
columns_count = df.shape[1] # Считаем число столбцов
for row in df:
    NaN_count = 0
    for i in row:
        if i == None:
            NaN_count +=1
    if NaN_count >= columns_count:
        df = df.drop(index=[row]) # Удаляем строку
print(df)
```

Почему-то не удаляет строки.

Comment: Как число NaN может превышать число столбцов?? В одной строке ровно <число столбцов > значений. Соответственно если все значения в строке NaN то их будет столько же сколько и столбцов

Comment: Нужно удалить из него строки, в которых число NaN превышает число столбцов с численными значениями или равно ему.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
res = df.dropna(thresh=len(df.columns)//2+1)
```

res:

```
      a     b     c     d
1  24.0  25.0  34.0   NaN
3  34.0   NaN   2.0  34.0
6  54.0   NaN  11.0  12.0
```

Comment: совсем забыл о параметре `thresh` - этот ответ более идиоматичный)

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, откуда в коде сумма 2+1? Что значат эти числа?

Comment: @AndrewTim `len(df.columns)` - это количество столбцов датафрейма. Делим его нацело на 2 (`//2`) получаем целое значение ближайшее к половине количества столбцов (меньшее или равное). +1 - дает ближайшее целое, большее или равное половине количества столбцов. Именно столько нам нужно NaN-значений в строке, чтобы ее удалить.

Answer (score 5):

```
threshold = df.shape[1] // 2

res = df.loc[df.isna().sum(axis=1).lt(threshold)]
```

результат:

```
In [13]: res
Out[13]:
      a     b     c     d
1  24.0  25.0  34.0   NaN
3  34.0   NaN   2.0  34.0
6  54.0   NaN  11.0  12.0
```